# shell script concatenate with space two string

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I’ve a shell script which need to provide the following pattern in the txt file

```
test0000 test0000@gmail.com
test0001 test0001@gmail.com
```

and so on until the stop condition (10 in this case...)

currently its not working and I tried with the following:

```
start=“test”
email=“@gmail.com"
start=0
stop=10


i=0
while [[ $i -le 10 ]]
do
  printf "%s%10d\n" "$start” "$i" "\n" "$start” "$email"
```

any idea how to resolve it ?  I got error: "@gmail.com:"  invalid number

Comment: Your quotes are all wrong. `“”` is not the same as `""`.

Comment: To be clear, your original code has only two placeholders in the format string; when you provide more than two following arguments, it starts over substituting from the first placeholder -- so assuming the quotes were fixed, `$start` would go in the `%s` and `$i` would go in the `%10d` as it should, but then `\n` would go in the next `%s` and `$start` would try to go into the `%10d`; since that value isn't a number, we get our error. (And then, having a final `$email` argument left over, if we *didn't* get that error we'd then try to evaluate the format string a third time).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
start='test'
email='@gmail.com'

for ((i=0; i<10; i++)); do
    printf '%s%04d   %s%04d%s\n' "$start" $i "$start" $i "$email"
done

test0000   test0000@gmail.com
test0001   test0001@gmail.com
test0002   test0002@gmail.com
test0003   test0003@gmail.com
test0004   test0004@gmail.com
test0005   test0005@gmail.com
test0006   test0006@gmail.com
test0007   test0007@gmail.com
test0008   test0008@gmail.com
test0009   test0009@gmail.com
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! its working, one question if I wan to read just the 'test0000' and 'test0000@gmail.com` with while IFS , how can I do that ? I mean put it to varibles ...

Comment: I am on mobile now so unable to test out a script. Look into formats of printf to get all the padding and alignment.

Comment: For reading this output into variable use: `while IFS= read -r str email; do declare -p str email; done < file`

Answer (score 2):

One more example with a different for loop syntax:

```
start="test"
email="@gmail.com"

for i in {0000..9};do
    echo "${start}$i  ${start}${i}${email}"
done

test0000  test0000@gmail.com
test0001  test0001@gmail.com
test0002  test0002@gmail.com
test0003  test0003@gmail.com
test0004  test0004@gmail.com
test0005  test0005@gmail.com
test0006  test0006@gmail.com
test0007  test0007@gmail.com
test0008  test0008@gmail.com
test0009  test0009@gmail.com
```

Or, with while loop:

```
start="test"
email="@gmail.com"
count=0

while [[ $count -lt 10 ]]; do
    printf '%s%04d   %s%04d%s\n' "$start" $count "$start" $count "$email"
    let count++
done
```